# Can durable queue be created in producer flow using solclientjs package in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, queue, solace

```
Does createDurableQueueDestination() method in solClientFactory creates durable queue if not exist in producer flow?
```

```
var messageText = 'Sample Message';
        var message = solace.SolclientFactory.createMessage();
        message.setDestination(solace.SolclientFactory.createDurableQueueDestination(producer.queueName));
        message.setBinaryAttachment(messageText);
        message.setDeliveryMode(solace.MessageDeliveryModeType.PERSISTENT);
        // Define a correlation key object
        const correlationKey = {
            name: "MESSAGE_CORRELATIONKEY",
            id: sequenceNr,
        };
        message.setCorrelationKey(correlationKey);
        try {
            producer.session.send(message);
            producer.log('Message #' + sequenceNr + ' sent to queue "' + producer.queueName + '", correlation key = ' + JSON.stringify(correlationKey));
        } catch (error) {
            producer.log(error.toString());
        }
```

```
nodejs package - solclientjs

Solace pubsub broker version - 10.1.1.29
```

var messageText = 'Sample Message';
var message = solace.SolclientFactory.createMessage();

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no
This question was also asked and answered over on the Solace Community forum: https://solace.community/discussion/1613/can-durable-queue-be-created-in-producer-flow-using-solclientjs-package-in-nodejs